# How can I create a new todo item in gitlab's gitlab.com?

Tags: gitlab

how can I create a todo item in gitlab hosted ? I am using the free account and see the todo item.

thanks

Comment: You can't. I asked them the same question. I even opened an issue with a feature proposal, but looks like they discard it. Go there and open an issue yourself, perhaps if they see there's more than one user interested they can reconsider, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

Currently is not possible to create custom todo items. However, there is a [feature proposal issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14068) where you can discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2016, this feature should be available from some time.

For instance, [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#add-or-resolve-to-do-items-on-tasks-objectives-and-key-results) (May 2023), both hosted or Cloud, mentions:

> ### Add or resolve to-do items on tasks, objectives, and key results
>
> We know that GitLab [To-Do List](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/todos.html) is a widely adopted feature, but it was not available on tasks, objectives, and key results.
>
> In this release, we’re introducing the ability to toggle a to-do item on or off from a work item record.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/add_or_resolve_a_todo_on_tasks_objectives_and_key_results.png -- Add or resolve to-do items on tasks, objectives, and key results]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/todos.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/9750).